# Java runtime execution

Tags: java

I am trying to execute a docker command from within Java. The docker command needs to be executed in the specified directory.

I found [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)) for executing an external command.

```
public Process exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir) throws IOException
```

I am unable to understand what exactly does this `envp` String array is used for? The documentation reads as:

> envp - array of strings, each element of which has environment variable settings in the format name=value, or null if the subprocess
>   should inherit the environment of the current process.

But I am unable to understand what it exactly means in the documentation. Could someone explain it with an example? What exactly do you need to pass as an argument here.

P.s.: I am using a *nix environment for dev/deployment.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`envp` - this is an abbreviation, I guess, from [**env**ironment **p**arameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) (or variables). For instance it can be path to libraries or something else.

If you do not need specify them, than pass it as `null`

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, dir);
```